# Placing a unique combinations into text file and detecting existing data

Tags: python, python-3.x, readfile

Here is my code to write data in a text file.

```
        with open('CodeList.txt') as f:
            if (strCode) in f.read():
                print ("The product code already exist")
           
            else:
                print ("The product code bas been added successfully")
                with open('CodeList.txt','a+') as g:
                   g.write(strCode +"\n")
```

The string written into the text file has a character from A to L e.g. "ABCDE"
It first detects if the string has already been added by checking the text file.

When I run the code, the first entry is "ABCD". This runs successfully.
However, when I want to add "ABC" into the text file, it fails as it detects the "ABC" in the previous entry.

I'm quite new to Python. Help much appreciated!

Comment: `f.readlines()`

Comment: doesn't work after a few tests. it just keeps adding data into new line.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you are processing the file as a single string instead of individual lines.

Try this instead:

```
if strCode in f.read().split("\n"):
    ...
```

Comment: `readlines()` is preferable because it does the work in one step and not `read()` and `split()`

Comment: agreed, but then you have to take into account the annoying \n at the end of each line.  For large files, it will be worth the trouble though.

Comment: i've tried f.readlines(). it doesn't detect any duplicates. it just keeps adding to the next line. f.read().split("\n"): worked well.

Comment: With readlines(), the condition would need to be something like `if strCode+"\n" in f.readlines():`